# Apollo Resolver Called Twice?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I use Apollo query components. When the data comes back from the resolver, I store it in component state, e.g.:

```
if (loading) {
    return (<></>);
} else {
    setMyData(data.myData);
}
```

But, since `setMyData` causes a refresh, the query component re-runs the query.

What is the best practices way to store the data to React component state without re-running the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, because the query result is already (global) state, you shouldn't do this at all. However, you could:

- Pass a `skip: myData` parameter to the query to prevent it from running if the state has been set.
- Fire the query only once, on mount. Assuming you're using hooks, you can use `useEffect` to run code on mount then use `client.query` to fire a query and set the state when the Promise it returns resolves.